# Qt test-unit: Error: undefined reference to `imp__ZN5Q

Tags: qt-creator, qtestlib, qttest

I am trying to create a "Qt unit test" following this [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtestlib-tutorial1.html). I created a new project: Qt Gui Application with a header file as mentioned and a class that contains the test function. I added `#CONFIG += testlib` to my `".pro" file`. However, when I run my code, I get this errors:

In function `simulateEvent':

- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest15defaultKeyDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest15defaultKeyDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest5qWarnEPKcS1_i'

then in function 'mouseEvent':

- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest5qWarnEPKcS1_i'

then in function 'simulateEvent' again:

- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest15defaultKeyDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest15defaultKeyDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest5qWarnEPKcS1_i'

then in function 'mouseEvent' again:

- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest17defaultMouseDelayEv'
- error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5QTest5qWarnEPKcS1_i'

I could not find any explanation for this as everything looks right . what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `QT += testlib`, without starting #

Answer (score 0):

Try Qt += declarative, testlib didn't work for me, but declarative did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case:
I used "delete" on an instance of a class what was inherited from QWidget.
I had to change the inheritance for my class from QWidget to QObject.